How can I fix the formatting of inbook apa biblatex citations?
I'm trying to cite a chapter from a book but can't seem to figure out how to change anything. I've somewhat accepted that I won't be able to get this to look exactly how I want, but any changes that make it closer would be much appreciated.
My university's formatting is: Authors (Year) ChapterTitle. In: Editors (eds.) BookTitle. Address, Publisher, pp X-X.
My reference currently looks like:

Fagerhol, M., Andersson, K. B., Naess-Andresen, C. F., Brandtzaeg, P. & Dale, I. (1990) Calprotectin (the L1 leukocyte protein). In V. L. Smith & J. R. Dedman (Eds.), Stimulus response coupling: The role of intracellular calcium-binding proteins. (pp. 187–210) CRC
Press.

I want it to look like:

Fagerhol, M., Andersson, K. B., Naess-Andresen, C. F., Brandtzaeg, P. & Dale, I. (1990) Calprotectin (the L1 leukocyte protein). In: Smith, V. L & Dedman, J. R. (eds.) Stimulus response coupling: The role of intracellular
calcium-binding proteins. Boca Raton, FL, USA, CRC Press, pp. 187–210.

My issues are (in order of priority):

Putting the page numbers at the end (without the brackets)

Adding in the address before the publisher

Adding a colon after In (so it becomes In:)

Fix the order of names in the book author/editor names, (change V. L. Smith into Smith, V. L.)

Change (Eds.) to (eds.)

Remove the comma after (eds.)


I've tried \renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\addcolon}. I've tried doing things with \renewbibmacro*{in:}{} but nothing I did changed anything. I've spent awhile looking for things and am at my wits end, so if you can even recommend me the direction to go, that would also help.
My MWE is as follows:
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, maxbibnames=99, isbn=false]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{%
    \mkbibacro{#1}\adddot}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\apablx@ifrevnameappcomma}{\@secondoftwo}
\makeatother
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \let\finalandcomma=\empty
}
  
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addspace}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@Inbook{Fag:90,
    author={Fagerhol, M.K. and Andersson, K. B. and Naess-Andresen, C. F. and Brandtzaeg, P. and Dale, I.},
    editor = {Smith, V. L. and Dedman, J. R.},
    title={Calprotectin (The \uppercase{L}1 Leukocyte Protein).},
    booktitle={Stimulus Response Coupling: The Role of Intracellular Calcium-Binding Proteins.},
    year={1990},
    publisher={CRC Press},
    address={Boca Raton, FL, USA},
    pages={187-210},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\cite{Fag:90}
\printbibliography[title={Reference List},heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}


If you're not required to use conforming APA style (which the biblatex apa style implements) don't use it for generic author/year formatting. It's a complex style not designed to be tweaked. So use the basic authoryear or ext-authoryear styles and work from there.
